# How do I turn 2 cubes into a 3rd cube in Webots?

Tags: webots

I'm trying to simulate an assembly factory. In which, several robots gather the necessary parts (objects A & B) and drop them off on the assembly table. Once A & B are both on the assembly table, I want an event to trigger which converts A & B into a third object C. This event can either be automatic or triggered via keyboard input. Objects A & B should disappear and object C should spawn at a specific coordinate.

I currently have ground & arm robots which transports objects A & B to the assembly table, but that's all I have right now. The ground robot is remotely controlled (Webot's Khepera 1 TCP/IP model), so timing will always be different.

My main question: **How do I remove objects A & B and spawn object C based on an event during simulation?**

A side question: How can the assembly table automatically detect when both objects A & B are on the table?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, the best way is probably use a Supervisor controller that monitors the simulation. It will track the positions of objects A and B and determine from their X, Y, Z coordinates if they are on the table or not. To understand how to track the position of an object, you can follow [this tutorial](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-8-the-supervisor#track-object-position-using-a-supervisor).

Then, you have two possibilities, the first one being more realistic and the second one being easier to implement and faster to execute.

1. When objects A and B are close enough to each other and/or some event happens, you can have the supervisor process delete objects A and B. To delete them, you should first get the root node of the scene using [wb_supervisor_node_get_root](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor#wb_supervisor_node_get_root), get its children field using [wb_supervisor_node_get_field](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor#wb_supervisor_node_get_field) and then [wb_supervisor_field_remove_mf](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor#wb_supervisor_field_remove_mf) to remove the A and B nodes from the list of children of the root node. Then, you will have to insert the C object at the location of A and B. To achieve this, you should use the [wb_supervisor_field_import_mf_node_from_string](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor#wb_supervisor_field_import_mf_node_from_string) and pass a string containing the description of node C (which could be a PROTO).
2. Instead of deleting and inserting objects A, B and C, it may be simpler and more efficient to move them around. Moving an object is very simple and explained in [this other tutorial](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/supervisor-programming#setting-the-position-of-robots). From the beginning, your scene should include objects A, B and C, but C should be initially very far away (like several kilometers away), so that it won't be visible. When you need to turn A and B into C, simply move A and B very far away, so that they are not visible any more, and move C at the previous location of A and B.

Comment: @adiga: sorry for this. My affiliation is clearly set in my profile and I thought it was sufficient. But I am happy to edit this post to make it even clearer. I am pointing to some existing tutorial because I believe it is not a good idea to copy/paste some existing tutorial. Otherwise, we should maintain them at several places, which is error prone and time consuming.

Comment: I didn't realize the tag and question were related to Cyberbotics company. My bad. You don't need to add a disclaimer if it is a link to the documentation the question is related to.